# reference multiple tables sqlite where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQL(ite) newb here,

I have a sqlite3 DB with two tables in it, let's call them table_a and table_b. table_a has 3.6 billion pairwise scores in the format:

```
mol_a,mol_b,score
int, int, real
int, int, real
...
```

I have added two blank columns to table_a : year_a and year_b which I want to popluate with data from table_b.

table b is composed of mol_id's and years in the format

```
mol_id,year
int,int
int,int
...
```

where mol_id corresponds to the possible ID's in table_a's mol_a and mol_b fields.

I think I can do this with an insert statement but I can't quite get multiple table syntax right in the where clause. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is what i'm trying:

```
INSERT INTO table_a.year_a 
SELECT year 
FROM table_b 
WHERE table_b.mol_id = table_a.mol_a;
```

but it would appear my TABLE.COLUMN syntax is wrong?

I'm sure there is a simple answer but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is it an ambiguity issue? Do you need to say `SELECT table_b.year` instead?

Comment: still get an error: no such column : table_a.mol_a

Comment: Well, *does* the column exist? I can't see any other reason you'd get a no such column error.

Comment: @McAdam331
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE tanimoto(mol_a INT, mol_b INT, score REAL, year_a INT, year_b INT);
CREATE TABLE date_ids(mol_id INT, year INT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, you want an `update`, not an `insert`:

```
update table_a
    set year = (select b.year from table_b b where b.mol_id = table_a.mol_a);
```

Comment: hmm this throws an: `code` Error: out of memory `code` error

Comment: i should add that I was not out of memory, it chewed up about 1GB and errors out

Comment: Then try splitting the updates; add something like `WHERE rowid BETWEEN 1000000 AND 1999999` to the outer query.

Comment: @CL Thanks! That looks like it's working when I do `BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000` I'll have to wrap it up in a python script to apply it to the rest of the db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want an update instead, i.e. to populate the new columns on the existing rows? In which case:

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET year_a = (SELECT year 
              FROM table_b 
              WHERE table_b.mol_id = table_a.mol_a),
    year_b = (SELECT year 
              FROM table_b 
              WHERE table_b.mol_id = table_a.mol_b),
```

Comment: same as with Gordon Linoff's similar solution, It uses up about 1GB of RAM and then errors with an 'out of memory'

Answer (score 0):

Try 1

```
INSERT INTO tanimoto (year_a) 
SELECT year FROM date_ids table_b 
WHERE table_b.mol_id = table_a.mol_a;
```

Try 2

```
INSERT INTO tanimoto (year_a) 
SELECT year FROM date_ids table_b 
WHERE Exists (Select 1 From tanimoto table_a Where table_a.mol_id = table_b.mol_a;
```

Here I'm a bit uncomfortable that I may not fully understand what you're trying to do. I see a lot of the otehr answers are mentioning that you *may* wnat and update. I'm reading that you want to *add* a new row into tanimoto with the year from date_ids where you get a match via *mol*. If that is not righ then yuo may wnat to atke a look at some of the update answers.

Comment: sqlite> INSERT INTO tanimoto (year_a) SELECT year FROM date_ids WHERE date_ids.mol_id = ta
nimoto.mol_a;
Error: no such column: tanimoto.mol_a

Comment: PS 
table_a = tanimoto
table_b = date_ids

Comment: So it looks like statement might be ok, but wrong column. Check that table_a has a column called year_a. Just guessing, but think that column in table_a is just year. If there IS a year_a in table_a, then check table_b for year, and both tables for moi_id.

Comment: when I run a .schema i get the following, it looks like everything is in order:     sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE tanimoto(mol_a INT, mol_b INT, score REAL, year_a INT, year_b INT);
CREATE TABLE date_ids(mol_id INT, year INT);

Comment: see edits. Here I'm a bit uncomfortable that I may not fully understand what you're trying to do. I see a lot of the other answers are mentioning that you _may_ want and update. I'm reading that you want to _add_ a new row into tanimoto with the year from date_ids where you get a match via _mol_. If that is not right then you may want to take a look at some of the update answers.